# How can I implement Elastislide (content-box) in a Bootstrap 3.3.5 (border-box) project?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, elastislide

I have trouble implementing an Elastislide Image Gallery with Bootstrap 3.

The Elastislide HTML, CSS and JQuery code I'm using is here: http://bit.ly/1o01x3x.

I'm working with Bootstrap tutorials and examples from W3Schools: http://bit.ly/1sJZYs4.

I have understood by searching other similar issues on StackOverflow that the problem has something to do with box-sizing. Bootstrap use box-sizing: border-box but Elastislide use box-sizing: content-box.

I have tried to use suggestions like this one: http://bit.ly/1ECEinM but with no success so my question is: how/where should I apply that code to make the Elastislide work with Bootstrap 3?

**gallery.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<title>Test</title>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge;chrome=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/elastislide.css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow&v1' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<noscript>
<style>
    .es-carousel ul{
        display:block;
    }
</style>
</noscript>

<script id="img-wrapper-tmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">    
    <div class="rg-image-wrapper">
        {{if itemsCount > 1}}
            <div class="rg-image-nav">
                <a href="#" class="rg-image-nav-prev">Previous Image</a>
                <a href="#" class="rg-image-nav-next">Next Image</a>
            </div>
        {{/if}}
        <div class="rg-image"></div>
        <div class="rg-loading"></div>
        <div class="rg-caption-wrapper">
            <div class="rg-caption" style="display:none;">
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="content">
                <h1>Responsive Image Gallery <span>A jQuery image gallery with a thumbnail carousel</span></h1>
                <div id="rg-gallery" class="rg-gallery">
                    <div class="rg-thumbs">
                        <!-- Elastislide Carousel Thumbnail Viewer -->
                        <div class="es-carousel-wrapper">
                            <div class="es-nav">
                                <span class="es-nav-prev">Previous</span>
                                <span class="es-nav-next">Next</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="es-carousel">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg" data-large="images/1.jpg" alt="image01" data-description="From off a hill whose concave womb reworded" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/2.jpg" data-large="images/2.jpg" alt="image02" data-description="A plaintful story from a sistering vale" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/3.jpg" data-large="images/3.jpg" alt="image03" data-description="A plaintful story from a sistering vale" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/4.jpg" data-large="images/4.jpg" alt="image04" data-description="My spirits to attend this double voice accorded" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/5.jpg" data-large="images/5.jpg" alt="image05" data-description="And down I laid to list the sad-tuned tale" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/6.jpg" data-large="images/6.jpg" alt="image06" data-description="Ere long espied a fickle maid full pale" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/7.jpg" data-large="images/7.jpg" alt="image07" data-description="Tearing of papers, breaking rings a-twain" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/8.jpg" data-large="images/8.jpg" alt="image08" data-description="Storming her world with sorrow's wind and rain" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/9.jpg" data-large="images/9.jpg" alt="image09" data-description="Upon her head a platted hive of straw" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/10.jpg" data-large="images/10.jpg" alt="image10" data-description="Which fortified her visage from the sun" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/11.jpg" data-large="images/11.jpg" alt="image11" data-description="Whereon the thought might think sometime it saw" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/12.jpg" data-large="images/12.jpg" alt="image12" data-description="The carcass of beauty spent and done" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/13.jpg" data-large="images/13.jpg" alt="image13" data-description="Time had not scythed all that youth begun" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/14.jpg" data-large="images/14.jpg" alt="image14" data-description="Nor youth all quit; but, spite of heaven's fell rage" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/15.jpg" data-large="images/15.jpg" alt="image15" data-description="Some beauty peep'd through lattice of sear'd age" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/16.jpg" data-large="images/16.jpg" alt="image16" data-description="Oft did she heave her napkin to her eyne" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/17.jpg" data-large="images/17.jpg" alt="image17" data-description="Which on it had conceited characters" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/18.jpg" data-large="images/18.jpg" alt="image18" data-description="Laundering the silken figures in the brine" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/19.jpg" data-large="images/19.jpg" alt="image19" data-description="That season'd woe had pelleted in tears" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/20.jpg" data-large="images/20.jpg" alt="image20" data-description="And often reading what contents it bears" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/21.jpg" data-large="images/21.jpg" alt="image21" data-description="As often shrieking undistinguish'd woe" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/22.jpg" data-large="images/22.jpg" alt="image22" data-description="In clamours of all size, both high and low" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/23.jpg" data-large="images/23.jpg" alt="image23" data-description="Sometimes her levell'd eyes their carriage ride" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/24.jpg" data-large="images/24.jpg" alt="image24" data-description="As they did battery to the spheres intend" /></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- End Elastislide Carousel Thumbnail Viewer -->
                    </div><!-- rg-thumbs -->
                </div><!-- rg-gallery -->
                <p class="sub">Want more Shakespeare? <a href="http://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/" target="_blank">http://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/</a></p>
            </div><!-- content -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"><!-- nothing here yet --></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**elastislide.css:**

```
/* Elastislide Style */
.es-carousel-wrapper{
    background: #101010;
    padding:10px 27px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.es-carousel{
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#000;
}
.es-carousel ul{
    display:none;
}
.es-carousel ul li{
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    display:block;
}
.es-carousel ul li a{
    display:block;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#222;
    opacity:0.8;
    -webkit-touch-callout:none;
    /* option */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.es-carousel ul li.selected a{
    border-color:#fff;
    opacity:1.0;
}
.es-carousel ul li a img{
    display:block;
    border:none;
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}
.es-nav span{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:8px;
    background:transparent url(../lib_images/img-gallery/nav_thumbs.png) no-repeat top left;
    width:14px;
    height:26px;
    margin-top:-13px;
    text-indent:-9000px;
    cursor:pointer;
    opacity:0.8;
}
.es-nav span.es-nav-next{
    right:8px;
    left:auto;
    background-position:top right;
}
.es-nav span:hover{
    opacity:1.0;
}
```

**rg-gallery.css:**

```
.rg-image-wrapper{
    position:relative;
    padding:20px 30px;
    background:transparent url(../lib_images/img-gallery/black.png) repeat top left;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    min-height:20px;

  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
}
.rg-image{
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:0px;

  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
}
.rg-image img{
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;

  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
}
.rg-image-nav a{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background:#000 url(../lib_images/img-gallery/nav.png) no-repeat -20% 50%;
    width:28px;
    height:100%;
    text-indent:-9000px;
    cursor:pointer;
    opacity:0.3;
    outline:none;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;

  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
}
.rg-image-nav a.rg-image-nav-next{
    right:0px;
    left:auto;
    background-position:115% 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;

  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
}
.rg-image-nav a:hover{
    opacity:0.8;

  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
}
.rg-caption {
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:15px;
    position:relative;

  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
}
.rg-caption p{
    font-size:11px;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Myriad Pro', Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height:16px;
    padding:0 15px;
    text-transform:uppercase;

  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
}
.rg-view{
    height:30px;

  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
}
.rg-view a{
    display:block;
    float:right;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    margin-right:3px;
    background:#464646 url(../lib_images/img-gallery/views.png) no-repeat top left;
    border:3px solid #464646;
    opacity:0.8;

  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
}
.rg-view a:hover{
    opacity:1.0;

  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
}
.rg-view a.rg-view-full{
    background-position:0px 0px;

  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
}
.rg-view a.rg-view-selected{
    background-color:#6f6f6f;
    border-color:#6f6f6f;

  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
}
.rg-view a.rg-view-thumbs{
    background-position:0px -16px;

  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
}
.rg-loading{
    width:46px;
    height:46px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    background:#000 url(../lib_images/img-gallery/ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat center center;
    margin:-23px 0px 0px -23px;
    z-index:100;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    opacity:0.7;

  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

**gallery.js:**

```
$(function() {
    // ======================= imagesLoaded Plugin ===============================
    // https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

    // $('#my-container').imagesLoaded(myFunction)
    // execute a callback when all images have loaded.
    // needed because .load() doesn't work on cached images

    // callback function gets image collection as argument
    //  this is the container

    // original: mit license. paul irish. 2010.
    // contributors: Oren Solomianik, David DeSandro, Yiannis Chatzikonstantinou

    $.fn.imagesLoaded       = function( callback ) {
    var $images = this.find('img'),
        len     = $images.length,
        _this   = this,
        blank   = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==';

    function triggerCallback() {
        callback.call( _this, $images );
    }

    function imgLoaded() {
        if ( --len <= 0 && this.src !== blank ){
            setTimeout( triggerCallback );
            $images.off( 'load error', imgLoaded );
        }
    }

    if ( !len ) {
        triggerCallback();
    }

    $images.on( 'load error',  imgLoaded ).each( function() {
        // cached images don't fire load sometimes, so we reset src.
        if (this.complete || this.complete === undefined){
            var src = this.src;
            // webkit hack from http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/eee6ab7b2da50e1f
            // data uri bypasses webkit log warning (thx doug jones)
            this.src = blank;
            this.src = src;
        }
    });

    return this;
    };

    // gallery container
    var $rgGallery          = $('#rg-gallery'),
    // carousel container
    $esCarousel         = $rgGallery.find('div.es-carousel-wrapper'),
    // the carousel items
    $items              = $esCarousel.find('ul > li'),
    // total number of items
    itemsCount          = $items.length;

    Gallery             = (function() {
            // index of the current item
        var current         = 0, 
            // mode : carousel || fullview
            mode            = 'carousel',
            // control if one image is being loaded
            anim            = false,
            init            = function() {

                // (not necessary) preloading the images here...
                $items.add('<img src="lib_images/img-gallery/ajax-loader.gif"/><img src="lib_images/img-gallery/black.png"/>').imagesLoaded( function() {
                    // add options
                    _addViewModes();

                    // add large image wrapper
                    _addImageWrapper();

                    // show first image
                    _showImage( $items.eq( current ) );

                });

                // initialize the carousel
                if( mode === 'carousel' )
                    _initCarousel();

            },
            _initCarousel   = function() {

                // we are using the elastislide plugin:
                // http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/12/elastislide-responsive-carousel/
                $esCarousel.show().elastislide({
                    imageW  : 65,
                    onClick : function( $item ) {
                        if( anim ) return false;
                        anim    = true;
                        // on click show image
                        _showImage($item);
                        // change current
                        current = $item.index();
                    }
                });

                // set elastislide's current to current
                $esCarousel.elastislide( 'setCurrent', current );

            },
            _addViewModes   = function() {

                // top right buttons: hide / show carousel

                var $viewfull   = $('<a href="#" class="rg-view-full"></a>'),
                    $viewthumbs = $('<a href="#" class="rg-view-thumbs rg-view-selected"></a>');

                $rgGallery.prepend( $('<div class="rg-view"/>').append( $viewfull ).append( $viewthumbs ) );

                $viewfull.on('click.rgGallery', function( event ) {
                        if( mode === 'carousel' )
                            $esCarousel.elastislide( 'destroy' );
                        $esCarousel.hide();
                    $viewfull.addClass('rg-view-selected');
                    $viewthumbs.removeClass('rg-view-selected');
                    mode    = 'fullview';
                    return false;
                });

                $viewthumbs.on('click.rgGallery', function( event ) {
                    _initCarousel();
                    $viewthumbs.addClass('rg-view-selected');
                    $viewfull.removeClass('rg-view-selected');
                    mode    = 'carousel';
                    return false;
                });

                if( mode === 'fullview' )
                    $viewfull.trigger('click');

            },
            _addImageWrapper= function() {

                // adds the structure for the large image and the navigation buttons (if total items > 1)
                // also initializes the navigation events

                $('#img-wrapper-tmpl').tmpl( {itemsCount : itemsCount} ).appendTo( $rgGallery );

                if( itemsCount > 1 ) {
                    // addNavigation
                    var $navPrev        = $rgGallery.find('a.rg-image-nav-prev'),
                        $navNext        = $rgGallery.find('a.rg-image-nav-next'),
                        $imgWrapper     = $rgGallery.find('div.rg-image');

                    $navPrev.on('click.rgGallery', function( event ) {
                        _navigate( 'left' );
                        return false;
                    }); 

                    $navNext.on('click.rgGallery', function( event ) {
                        _navigate( 'right' );
                        return false;
                    });

                    // add touchwipe events on the large image wrapper
                    $imgWrapper.touchwipe({
                        wipeLeft            : function() {
                            _navigate( 'right' );
                        },
                        wipeRight           : function() {
                            _navigate( 'left' );
                        },
                        preventDefaultEvents: false
                    });

                    $(document).on('keyup.rgGallery', function( event ) {
                        if (event.keyCode == 39)
                            _navigate( 'right' );
                        else if (event.keyCode == 37)
                            _navigate( 'left' );    
                    });

                }

            },
            _navigate       = function( dir ) {

                // navigate through the large images

                if( anim ) return false;
                anim    = true;

                if( dir === 'right' ) {
                    if( current + 1 >= itemsCount )
                        current = 0;
                    else
                        ++current;
                }
                else if( dir === 'left' ) {
                    if( current - 1 < 0 )
                        current = itemsCount - 1;
                    else
                        --current;
                }

                _showImage( $items.eq( current ) );

            },
            _showImage      = function( $item ) {

                // shows the large image that is associated to the $item

                var $loader = $rgGallery.find('div.rg-loading').show();

                $items.removeClass('selected');
                $item.addClass('selected');

                var $thumb      = $item.find('img'),
                    largesrc    = $thumb.data('large'),
                    title       = $thumb.data('description');

                $('<img/>').load( function() {

                    $rgGallery.find('div.rg-image').empty().append('<img src="' + largesrc + '"/>');

                    if( title )
                        $rgGallery.find('div.rg-caption').show().children('p').empty().text( title );

                    $loader.hide();

                    if( mode === 'carousel' ) {
                        $esCarousel.elastislide( 'reload' );
                        $esCarousel.elastislide( 'setCurrent', current );
                    }

                    anim    = false;

                }).attr( 'src', largesrc );

            },
            addItems        = function( $new ) {

                $esCarousel.find('ul').append($new);
                $items      = $items.add( $($new) );
                itemsCount  = $items.length; 
                $esCarousel.elastislide( 'add', $new );

            };

        return { 
            init        : init,
            addItems    : addItems
        };

    })();

    Gallery.init();

    /*
    Example to add more items to the gallery:

    var $new  = $('<li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg" data-large="images/1.jpg" alt="image01" data-description="From off a hill whose concave womb reworded" /></a></li>');
    Gallery.addItems( $new );
    */
});
```

There are also jquery.easing.1.3.js, jquery.elastislide.js, and jquery.tmpl.min.js. Don't know if I have to paste that code too?

Comment: Hi Torbjorn, please include your code in the question directly, rather than linking to off-site resources. Otherwise your question risks being closed!

Comment: @TylerH Didn't know that. Quite a lot of code so I thought it was easier to just link to it. Thanks for telling me :)

Comment: Typically we ask that the code be just the minimal amount needed (see [MCVEs](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) to cut down on the infamous Wall of Code. This has the added bonus of often helping the user solve their own problem, since many issues are in not being able to isolate what the problem actually is. If your question does, in fact, need tons of code, then that's fine, Just be darn sure that all the code is really required ;-)

Comment: @TylerH It's probably a CSS issue so maybe the .js file is overkill, but I'm not 100% sure. That's the heart of the matter in this question, I kind of know the solution but I have no clue WHERE to put it in the code :P